Is it considered Mahr el mithl
Salam aleykum,
I hope you are well.
My husband has just offered me a dowry. We are already married and hadn't talked about it before and during the nikkah.
Is the dowry we've just agreed on considered "Mahr Al mithl"?
If this dowry is considered "Mahr Al Mithl".
Do I have the right to ask him to REDUCE the amount of the dowry?
BarakAllah ufikum.

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Could you please elaborate on what makes you think that this dowry is Mahr al-Mithl? Was the dowry not specified at the time of nikah? Further, it could be helpful what denomination of Islam you consider yourself following. You could make use of the edit button/link at the bottom of your post and add these information.

Mahr al-Mithl literally means equality mahr, so it is either a mahr value which is common in a certain place or the same mahr as given to other wives. Your question doesn't give any hint that either of these applies... it looks for me like there's information missing. See [ask].

The "Mahr Al mithl" is a legal amount that should be determined by a legal expert; the husband himself cannot decide on or offer its amount. And also, the "Mahr Al mithl" is the right of a woman. A woman can reduce the amount of her "Mahr Al mithl", after it has been determined by forgiving and giving away all or part of it, similar to any other properties she owns. But if she wants, she can ask for all of it as her right.
References:
https://www.al-islam.org/marriage-according-five-schools-islamic-law-muhammad-jawad-mughniyya/disagreement-between-spouses
https://fa.wikifeqh.ir/%D9%85%D9%87%D8%B1_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%AB%D9%84

Salam aleykum thank you for your answer. So the mahr we fixed together ( After nikkah) is a simple mahr, not a mahr al mithl ?

@Aïcha no it is none of them. the mehr is fixed at marriage. not later. and the mahr al mithl has its own formula and is not determined as how much the husband likes. so what you have fixed is none of them. it nothing Islamic in fact. I do not what it is.
